# Oozie custom asynchronous action

Tags: hadoop, asynchronous, oozie

I have a problem implementing a custom asynchronous action in Oozie. My class extends from ActionExecutor, and overwrites the methods initActionType, start, end, check, kill and isCompleted.

In the start method, i want to to start a YARN job, that is implemented through my BiohadoopClient class. To make the call asynchronous, i wrapped the client.run() method in a Callable:

```
public void start(final Context context, final WorkflowAction action) {
...
  Callable<String> biohadoop = new Callable<String>() {
    BiohadoopClient client = new BiohadoopClient();
    client.run();
  }

  // submit callable to executor
  executor.submit(biohadoop);

  // set the start data, according to https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.1/DG_CustomActionExecutor.html
  context.setStartData(externalId, callBackUrl, callBackUrl);
...
}
```

This works fine, and for example when I use my custom action in a fork/join manner, the execution of the actions runs in parallel.

Now, the problem is, that Oozie remains in a RUNNING state for this actions. It seems impossible to change that to a completed state. The check() method is never called by Oozie, the same is true for the end() method. It doesn't help to set the context.setExternalStatus(), context.setExecutionData() and context.setEndData() manually in the Callable (after the client.run() has finished). I tried also to queue manually an ActionEndXCommand, but without luck.

When I wait in the start() method for the Callable to complete, the state gets updated correctly, but the execution in fork/join isn't parallel anymore (which seem logic, as the execution waits for the Callable to complete).

[How external clients notify Oozie workflow with HTTP callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671386/how-external-clients-notify-oozie-workflow-with-http-callback/20680301#20680301) didn't help, as using the callback seems to change nothing (well, I can see that it happened in the log files, but beside from that, nothing...). Also, the answer mentioned, that the SSH action runs asynchronously, but I haven't found out how this is done. There is some wrapping inside a Callable, but at the end, the call() method of the Callable is invoked directly (no submission to an Executor).

So far I haven't found any example howto write an asynchronous custom action. Can anybody please help me?

Thanks

**Edit**

Here are the implementations of initActionType(), start(), check(), end(), the callable implementation can be found inside the start() action.

The callable is submitted to an executor in the start() action, after which its shutdown() method is invoked - so the executor shuts down after the Callable has finished. As next step, context.setStartData(externalId, callBackUrl, callBackUrl) is invoked.

```
private final AtomicBoolean finished = new AtomicBoolean(false);

public void initActionType() {
    super.initActionType();
    log.info("initActionType() invoked");
}

public void start(final Context context, final WorkflowAction action)
        throws ActionExecutorException {
    log.info("start() invoked");

    // Get parameters from Node configuration
    final String parameter = getParameters(action.getConf());

    Callable<String> biohadoop = new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            log.info("Starting Biohadoop");

            // No difference if check() is called manually
            // or if the next line is commented out
            check(context, action);

            BiohadoopClient client = new BiohadoopClient();
            client.run(parameter);
            log.info("Biohadoop finished");             

            finished.set(true);
            // No difference if check() is called manually
            // or if the next line is commented out
            check(context, action);

            return null;
        }
    };

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    biohadoopResult = executor.submit(biohadoop);
    executor.shutdown();

    String externalId = action.getId();
    String callBackUrl = context.getCallbackUrl("finished");
    context.setStartData(externalId, callBackUrl, callBackUrl);
}

public void check(final Context context, final WorkflowAction action)
        throws ActionExecutorException {
    // finished is an AtomicBoolean, that is set to true,
    // after Biohadoop has finished (see implementation of Callable)
    if (finished.get()) {
        log.info("check(Context, WorkflowAction) invoked - 
            Callable has finished");
        context.setExternalStatus(Status.OK.toString());
        context.setExecutionData(Status.OK.toString(), null);
    } else {
        log.info("check(Context, WorkflowAction) invoked");
        context.setExternalStatus(Status.RUNNING.toString());
    }
}

public void end(Context context, WorkflowAction action)
        throws ActionExecutorException {
    log.info("end(Context, WorkflowAction) invoked");
    context.setEndData(Status.OK, Status.OK.toString());
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you have implemented the check() and  initActionType() methods and how are you implementing the call() method in the Callable?

Comment: @SSaikia_JtheRocker: I have added the implementations

Answer (score 0):

One thing - I can see you are shutting down the executor right after you have submitted the job - `executor.shutdown();`. That might be causing the issue. Could you please try moving this statement to the `end()` method instead?

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I tried it, but it made no difference. The JavaDoc is pretty clear about using shutdown: `Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.

This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution`
Maybe you have an other idea?

Comment: @gappc: My doubt is that somehow the AtomicBoolean variable is not updated or something. Please remove the check method statements from the start() method and then check if the log messages you are doing inside check() are visible. Also, log the value of finished.get(). Would have been much better if you could test it using a JUnit test case.

Comment: The AtomicBoolean is set correctly, I can see that from the log files, if I call check() manually (different log output). If I remove the manual check() calls, both check() and end() are not called at all. For the case of JUnit tests: you are right :) But at the current stage, where the desired solution is not working at all, the additional effort is not worth - at least in my opinion. I got some answers from the oozie mailing list, that I'm trying out now, I will let you know about the progress

Answer (score 0):

In the end I didn't find a "real" solution to the problem. The solution that worked for me was to implement an action, that invokes the Biohadoop instances in parallel using the Java Executor framework. After the invokation, I wait (still inside the action) for the threads to finish